# FastTrack proposal execution fails with "ProposalMissing" but is stored in democracy.publicProps

Tags: storage, democracy

I am trying to test Fast Track of proposals via PolkadotJS dashboard, but I'm running into an error I can't explain.  Note this is on a local relay chain where we have set up various members of Alice...Ferdie as Council/TC .

1. I submit notePreimage for a forceTransfer via Governance -> Democracy -> Submit preimage.
2. After this is in a block, I copy the preimage hash (`0xa4c5c8dce6baf661e66af7a75c3e9afe24fcad3a88b2e5e4272f130d9c941701`)and submit a proposal in the same pane via Submit proposal.
3. I verify that the proposal exists in storage:

```
democracy.publicProps:
[
  [
    0
    0xa4c5c8dce6baf661e66af7a75c3e9afe24fcad3a88b2e5e4272f130d9c941701
    5FHneW46xGXgs5mUiveU4sbTyGBzmstUspZC92UhjJM694ty
  ]
]
```

3. I submit a democracy.fastTrack motion via Governance -> TechnicalCommittee -> Proposals -> Submit proposal, using the above hash.
4. I verify that the proposal exists in the collective's storage:

```
technicalCommittee.proposalOf: Option<Call>
{
  args: {
    proposal_hash: 0xa4c5c8dce6baf661e66af7a75c3e9afe24fcad3a88b2e5e4272f130d9c941701
    voting_period: 100
    delay: 2
  }
  method: fastTrack
  section: democracy
}
```

5. I submit enough votes for the proposal to meet the threshold (2). I also tried this with 3/2 votes (exceeding the threshold).
6. Waiting for all votes to be in a block, I close the proposal.
7. I see events `technicalCommittee.Closed`, `technicalCommittee.Approved`, then `technicalCommittee.execute` fails with `ProposalMissing`.

I see a number of places where that might be thrown but it seems they would never get to the dispatch stage in `do_approve_proposal` if the proposal were missing. So I don't know why this is failing or how to get this Fast Track to go through. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your runtime configurations.

But generally, you need to open a council motion first.

It will be `council::propose(democracy::external proposal)`.

After this passed. There will be an external proposal.

[image]

And you could only fast track this one. You can not fast track the normal proposal.

Comment: This fixed it.  For future readers: I deleted my old, out of date message; now you can submit preimages directly to the Preimage pane/pallet and those can now be used by democracy pallet.